# connecting to the backend in react it gives error 400 bad request in mern application

Tags: 400-bad-request

```
const handleSubmit= async (e)=>
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        const addUser={name,email,age};
        console.log(addUser);
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/" , 
        {
            method:"POST",
            body:JSON.stringify(addUser),

            headers:{
               "Contetnt-Type":"application/json",
               "Accept":"application/json"
            },
            
            
           
        });
        const result= await response.json();
```

POST http://localhost:5000/ 400 (Bad Request)

handleSubmit @ Create.jsx:17

callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164

invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213

invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277

invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291

executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041

processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073

processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086

dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097

(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288

batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140

batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991

dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287

dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465

dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457

dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430

Show 15 more frames

Show less

VM35:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'B', "Bad Request" is not valid JSON